# How to dereference from an array of struct poiners

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dereference

Say I have this `struct`:

```
struct card{
  char num;
   char suit;
 };
```

And this array of struct pointers:

```
struct card *deck[52];
```

And then this method to intialize a deck of cards (this is for a device drive hence kmalloc):

```
static int __init_deck(void){
// allocate some memory
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        deck[i] = kmalloc(sizeof(struct card), GFP_KERNEL);
        if(!deck[i]){
            printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to allocate memory.");
        }
    }

    returnValue = misc_register(&deck_dev);
    if(returnValue){
         printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to register\n");
    }

// give the card structs some values in the deck. 
// Spades
    for(i = 0; i < 13; i++){
                  // why does this not work??
        *(deck[i].num) = (char)i;
        *(deck[i].suit) = 'S';
    }
// Hearts
    for(i = 13; i < 16; i++){
        deck[i].num = (char)i;
        deck[i].suit = 'H';
    }
// Diamonds
    for(i = 26; i < 39; i++){
        deck[i].num = (char)i;
        deckk[i].suit = 'D';
    }
// Clubs
    for(i = 39; i < 52; i++){
        deck[i].num = (char)i;
        deck[i].suit = 'C';
    }

    return returnValue;
  }
```

I declared an array of size 52 that contains pointers to `struct card`. I am trying to obviously deference the struct contained at a position in the array so I can add "stuff" to that struct. Why don't my dereferences as I have them in one case work?

Comment: except for spades loop, replace `deck[i].num` with `deck[i]->num` and `deck[i].suit` with `deck[i]->suit`

Comment: Also, `for(i = 13; i < 16; i++){` should perhaps be `26` rather than `16`. And maybe the `num` should be taken `mod 13`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would that matter? Don't they both accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I have to ask, why do you have a deck of cards in a kernel device driver - let alone 52 individually-malloc'd cards?

Comment: It's going to be hard to win with hearts given `// Hearts` and
    `for(i = 13; i < 16; i++){`.  Surely you can do better using an array of characters for the suits and a double loop rather than writing almost the same loop out 4 times.

Comment: Excellent question @MattMcNabb, dumb project for school.

Comment: @OP, `deck[i]` is a POINTER. You cannot do `.` on a pointer. The `.` is for accessing struct members. `deck[i]` is not a struct, it's a pointer. You have to dereference it. `*` and `->` are dereference operators.

Answer (score 4):

You are dereferencing here incorrectly, `*(deck[i].num) = (char)i;`.

First you have to dereference the pointer then you access its member.

```
 (*deck[i]).num = (char)i;
```

Or using the `->` operator:

```
 deck[i]->num = (char)i;
```

Comment: Ahh, put the asterisk on the wrong side of the parenthesis, that makes sense though. Thanks!

Comment: @user3268401 because of the the problem you just now faced -> (structure arrow operator) was built.so that you easily access without using dot operator.....:)